Is this about notation of Heaviside function or is my simplification in-correct?
I am reading some introductory material on Green's function from the book "Applications of Green's functions in science and engineering",Greenberg. I have a question related to a boundary value problem example on loaded string. This problem is specified using the equation $u''(x)=\phi(x)$ subjected to BCs $u(x=0)=u(x=0)=0$, where $\phi(x)$ is the load function on the string.
In this example, the Green's function is given as $G(\xi,x) = (\xi-x)H(\xi-x)+(x-1)\xi$. In this equation, I expanded the Heaviside function $H(\xi-x)= 1 \rightarrow\xi >x, 0 \rightarrow\xi < x$. Now, with this Heaviside function, $G(\xi,x)$ is simplified as $G(\xi,x) = x(\xi-1) \rightarrow\xi > x, (x-1)\xi \rightarrow\xi < x$.
In the textbook however, the simplification is $G(\xi,x) = x(\xi-1) \rightarrow \xi \geq x, (x-1)\xi \rightarrow \xi \leq x$. I don't understand how the $\geq$ and $\leq$ signs are included here. Does this have to do with the denotion of Heaviside function or is it related to some physical aspects of the problem ?
I have used $\rightarrow$ to denote the piecewise function because I could not type it in correct format here.

To have a clear definition of the Heavyside function, its definition is as follows (see heavyside function):
$H(x) = \begin{cases}
1 & x \geq 0 \\
0 & \ x<0
\end{cases}$
In this case one what use $G(\xi,x)=x(\xi−1)→\xi≥x, (x−1)\xi→ \xi <x$. Using only the inequality or the strict inequality does not make sense in my understanding, because in this case the function $G(\xi,x)$ is not clearly defined at the point x.
